# Opencv 4 Android detect boxes

Tags: android, opencv, detect, rectangles, box

i'm developing an Android app that recognizes, from a store shelf image, all the boxes (products) present on the shelf.

My approach so far is the following:

1. grayscale
2. bilateral filter (or GaussianBlur, but I've found that using bilateral filter is better to preserve edges)
3. adaptive threshold
4. dilate (don't know if it's necessary)
5. canny
6. findContours

So, if the source image is simple, (like a b/w drawing of a shelf and some boxes) it can detect them, but with real images of shelves it isn't working.

The main problem is that single boxes have different "foreground" colors and logos, and my steps detect also all the edges of the "inner" box (i.e., the colours inside the edges of the box) and gives me totally nosense results.
For simplicity I'll show belows my intermediate results and the source image:

1)source
[image: source image]

2)grayscale
[image: grayscaled image]

3)bilateral filtering (in this case was gaussianBlur)
[image: bilateral]

4)adaptive threshold
[image: adaptive thresh]

5)dilation
[image: dilation]

6)canny
[image: Canny]

As you can see, because I cannot remove the foreground of each box, also all the edges given by the logos or text come into play and noises my results.

How can I overcome this problem?

My ony idea is trying to "remove" or decolouring the inner boxes, but i don't konw how to do it!
Thanks to all!

Comment: Expect to hit a problem with environment light.

Comment: I already know that light could be a problem. but first I have to understand how to avoid my first problem.

Comment: I'm thinking your problem is partially related to the light problem, but i'm not quite sure. I hope you get it working.

Comment: Yes, I know. But i guess that using some thresholding on type of colors can avoid partially this problem. Another idea that i have to try is the usge of the hierarchy after find contours, in which I can detect inside contours of a parent and then delete them.